# How to rollback applied patch in OWB (Oracle Warehouse Builder)

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse

I was wrongly applied the oracle generic patch(p24615704_112040_Generic) to my current OWB. However, I need to rollback this patch because for apply another patch.

Comment: What is your OS and database version?

Comment: My OS is  AIX 7.1 and Database is Oracle Database 11gR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands step by step.

Step 1: Export the following variables

```
    export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$PATH
```

Step 2: opatch rollback -id 24615704